# SQL QUERY with SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

please help Im juste starting  with SQL

Given the following table:

```
CUSTOMER     TRANSACTION_CODE     AMOUNT
--------     ----------------     -------
001           WE01                 100.00
001           WE02                  80.00
002           WE01                 120.00
002           WE02                  22.00
```

I want to the SQL query to sum up transaction for same customer ( I dont need to display TRANSACTION CODE)

```
CUSTOMER      AMOUNT
--------     --------- 
001           180.00
002           144.00
```

I did different test with `group by`and `SUM` but I cannot get the proper syntax - your help is appreciated like always

Comment: Your output seems to be wrong. You should have 142 amount for 002 customer

Comment: yes output is 142.00- sorry

Comment: This kind of thing should be in any SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple grouping query. Try this:

```
SELECT customer, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM myTable
GROUP BY customer
```

**EDIT** Here is an example with joins:

```
SELECT table1.customer, SUM(table1.amount) AS amount
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.col1 = table1.col1
GROUP BY table1.customer
```

Comment: worked great. however I did not mention I have a INNER JOIN so the group by giving me an error if I group by customer. I tried with table_name.customer but it failed too.

Comment: Post your query so we can help you. There is no problem in using grouping with joins. I've added an example with joins.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `group by` for grouping one or more fields, and in the `select` part of the statement use a `sum` function to aggregate values from a column.

here you can read everything about [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html)

Grouped by CUSTOMER and TRANSACTION_CODE

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, TRANSACTION_CODE, SUM(AMOUNT) as AMOUNT
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER, TRANSACTION_CODE
```

Grouped by CUSTOMER only

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, TRANSACTION_CODE, SUM(AMOUNT) as AMOUNT
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER, TRANSACTION_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

You should group by coustomer

```
select customer, sum(amount) as amount
from my_table  
group by  customer 
order by customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track!

Try this:

```
select customer, sum(amount) 
from your_table 
group by customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the aggregate sum function in select and group by customer.

```
SELECT Customer, SUM(amount)

From Tablename

GROUP BY Customer;
```